Will Kubernetes attempt to assign a node port that has already been manually assigned?
I have manually assigned a node port to a service like so... I'm running on Kube 1.27
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: foo
  ports:
    - port: 1775
      targetPort: 1775
      nodePort: 31775
      name: bar


If I understand the docs correctly, if I pick the port I risk having a conflict. But is it the same when Kubernetes tries to assign a node port or is that the potential conflict? I.e: Kubernetes can randomly pick 31775 and it will fail deployment? Will redeploying pick a whole new random port?
Edit:
As requested here is the doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport-custom-port

From what I understand from this documentation it will only assign a node port if you dont assign its value. I would also like to suggest if possible please share the documentation you are reading.

Updated with doc. Also understood. I know it will assign a port if you don't tell it. I'm asking is it smart enough to know what previous ports where assigned either by itself or manually (by a user) so it wont attempt to assign any of those ports. I'm guessing yes because it would always have collision then.
